# Serving Up Word Document From SIlverlight

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I have a silverlight app. I want it to serve up a word document through it.

The document will not exist anywhere physically, but will be coming into my silverlight app via a webservice call.

Is this possible?

Comment: Define "serve up". Does the document already exist?

Comment: The document will not exist anywhere physically, but will be coming into my silverlight app via a webservice call.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [TextGlow](http://textglow.codeplex.com/)

> TextGlow is a Silverlight 2.0 demo application for viewing Word 2007 documents in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

This may be possible using the COM APIs to open the file in MS Word.